# Android Emulator is not working in Lenovo G510

Tags: android, emulation

I am using laptop Lenovo G510, I want to run android emulator on my laptop but its not working. I also enable hyper v and virtualization but when i run my application in android studio it says VT-x in not enable and  not supported in your computer. My windows phone emulator is working properly in my laptop but android emulator is not working. please help me what should i do ?? To run emulator of android studio.

Comment: Turn on VT in your BIOS.

Comment: Are you using the official emulator, or Genymotion? The official emulator shouldn't require VT-x.

Comment: I use official emulator which is provided by android studio